# C# WPF Make DataGrid TemplateColumn ComboBox editable based on it's ItemsSource

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

How can I make a **ComboBox** **editable** based on whether the item in the column has an `ItemsSource` property that is set to `null` as the column is being generated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add style to `ComboBox` with `DataTrigger` where you will check if  `ItemsSource` is null.

Here is very simple example:

```
<Window x:Class="Q52063400.MainWindow"
      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
      xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
      xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
      mc:Ignorable="d"
      Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
  <Grid>
      <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
          <DataGrid.Columns>
              <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name}" />
              <DataGridTextColumn Header="Surname" Binding="{Binding Surname}" />
              <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="City">
                  <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                      <DataTemplate>
                          <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Cities}" 
                                    SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedCity, Mode=TwoWay}">
                              <ComboBox.Style>
                                  <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
                                      <Setter Property="IsEditable" Value="False"/>
                                      <Style.Triggers>
                                          <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Cities}" Value="{x:Null}">
                                              <Setter Property="IsEditable" Value="True"/>
                                          </DataTrigger>
                                      </Style.Triggers>
                                  </Style>
                              </ComboBox.Style>
                          </ComboBox>
                      </DataTemplate>
                  </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
              </DataGridTemplateColumn>
          </DataGrid.Columns>
      </DataGrid>
  </Grid>
</Window>
```

Code-behind:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
   public MainWindow()
   {
       InitializeComponent();

       DataContext = GetItems();
   }

   public List<Person> GetItems ()
   {
       return new List<Person>()
       {
           new Person {Name = "John", Surname = "Rocky", Cities = new List<string> { "New York City", "Washington D.C.", "Chicago" } },
           new Person {Name = "John", Surname = "Rocky"},
           new Person {Name = "John", Surname = "Rocky", Cities = new List<string> { "Baltimore", "San Francisco", "Boston" } }
       };
   }
}

public class Person
{
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public string Surname { get; set; }

   public IEnumerable<string> Cities { get; set; }
   public string SelectedCity { get; set; }
}
```

Example with different editor based on ItemsSource:

```
...
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="City">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>                           
            <Grid>
                <TextBox Text="{Binding SelectedCity, Mode=TwoWay}">
                    <TextBox.Style>
                        <Style TargetType="TextBox">
                            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                            <Style.Triggers>
                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Cities}" Value="{x:Null}">
                                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                                </DataTrigger>
                            </Style.Triggers>
                        </Style>
                    </TextBox.Style>
                </TextBox>
                <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Cities}" 
                      SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedCity, Mode=TwoWay}">
                    <ComboBox.Style>
                        <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
                            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                            <Style.Triggers>
                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Cities}" Value="{x:Null}">
                                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                                </DataTrigger>
                            </Style.Triggers>
                        </Style>
                    </ComboBox.Style>
                </ComboBox>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
...
```

Comment: Works perfectly. Thank you!

Comment: I am no longer able to select items from the ComboBox selection because IsEditable is set to False. IsEditable creates a text box, and I was under the assumption the IsReadOnly handled the ability to update values.

Comment: Is set to False because ItemsSource is null, would you want to also block the ability to write to ComboBox ?

Comment: The entire column actually needs to be able to write to ComboBox. I thought that the `IsEditable` Property controlled the editable textbox that displayed within the ComboBox.

Comment: In the answer I gave you the template how you can change the behavior of control under different circumstances, you should read MSDN doc where you find a good explanation about IsEditable and IsReadOnly properties and apply this solution to your requirements: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.combobox.iseditable?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#remarks

Comment: Thank you, your example made it easier to understand how to use the Setter and Trigger flags.

Is it possible to determine whether a ComboBox or TextBox should be displayed based on the ItemsSource? I feel that it would be more beneficial to display a TextBox when ItemsSource is null

Comment: Check my answer again, I gave you sample code to do that.

Comment: Fantastic. Thank you, I can definitely work with this.

Answer (score 1):

Simply check combo box itemsource on selected index changed event or on main window  load and then set the combobox `IsEditable="true"` for that selected item.

Comment: After implementing this, the IsEditable property is set to items that have an ItemsSource after a few seconds, which makes it editable.

Comment: Are you creating combobox at run time ?

Comment: Yes, the ComboBox is created at runtime

Comment: Can you share your code? At what event you are trying to make it editable?